# Existence of minimal projection in a sub-algebra of compact operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

[image]

I am not sure that I explained to myself the missing details in the proof right, so please check my explanations. (The proof is taken from "$C^*$ -Algebras by Example"-Davidson) 
First, I don't know how we use the fact that A is a positive operator. We can assume it's self adjoint just to have non-zero point in it's spectrum. 
 For the second part of the proof: Let $T \in E \mathscr{A}E$ self-adjoint non-scalar multiple of E. 
 $T$ is compact self-adjoint, thus the spectrum of $T$ is finite or  a sequence converges to zero+zero itself, and each element in the spectrum, besides zero, is an eigenvalue with finite dimensional eigenspace. If we denote by $P_{\lambda i}$ the projections onto the eigenspaces $W_{\lambda i}$, then $T=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda_i P_{\lambda i}$. 
 Now, As $Im(P_{\lambda i})=W_{\lambda i} \subseteq Im(E)$ $\forall i$  we conclude $P_{\lambda i} \le E \; \forall i$ . But $E$ is minimal, so $\forall i$  $P_{\lambda i} = E$. 
Thus, we can write $T=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda_i E$ and we got a contradiction, as we assumed $T$ is not a scalar multilpe of $E$. 
 I am not only worried that there are mistakes in my proof, but also I have a feeling I overcomplicate it.
 Thank you for your time.

 **EDIT:** Ok, maybe another approach: 
  - If the spectrum contains exactly one non-zero point $\lambda$ which is an eigenvalue with projection $P_\lambda$ , from the arguments above, we get $T=\lambda P_\lambda =\lambda E$, a contradiction. 
 -If the spectrum contains at least two non-zero eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$ then we conclude from minimality of $E$, as above, $P_\lambda=P_\mu=E$ but this is not a possibility because $P_\lambda$ is orthogonal to $P_\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you make it unncessarily complicated. By the minimality of $E$,  you have $P_{\lambda_i}=P_{\lambda_j}$ for all $i,j$. But each $P_{\lambda_i}$ is the particular projection corresponding to $\lambda_i$; so $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ for all $i,j$ (projections corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other). Thus $T=\lambda_1\,E$.

Comment: Very simple. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. Davidson's book is a good place to learn how to write proofs that are concrete and direct.

Comment: I shall be grateful if you could clarify what is meant by minimal projection? I am reading this chapter on my own .

Comment: It means that it does not have a proper subprojection. In a context with lots of projections, like the algebra of compact operators or for instance a von Neumann algebra, it equivalently means that $E\mathfrak A E=\mathbb CE$, as the Lemma says.

Comment: This minimal projection might not be unique right?

Comment: And should it always be of rank 1.

Comment: No, a rank-one projection is minimal, but a minimal projection needs not to have rank 1, as minimal is a relative notion. For instance, in $M_3(\mathbb C)$ consider the subalgebra $$A=\{a\,E_{11}+b\,(E_{22}+E_{33}):\ a,b\in\mathbb C\}.$$ The projection $E_{11}$  is minimal in $A$, but so is $E_{22}+E_{33}$.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help . This means a lot to me .

Comment: There is another question that I wanted to ask . For the second part of the proof we taking $T\in E\mathfrak A E$ self adjoint that is not a scalar multiple of $E$. Shouldn't we take $T\in E\mathfrak A E$ ( not necessarily self adjoint )  ? I couldn't understand why it suffices to show for self adjoints only .

Comment: Every element is a linear combination of selfadjoints. If you show that all selfadjoints are scalar multiples of the identity, it follows immediately that all elements are.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, could you please clarify how does the second line of the proof follow from continuous functional calculus (Theorem I.3.3)….

Comment: By “spectral projection” corresponding to a non zero eigenvalue, say, $\lambda$ I assume the projection onto the $\ker(A-\lambda)$…. But then why it belongs to the C*-algebra generated by A?? How to write $P$ as $f(A)$??

Comment: The nonzero elements of the spectrum of a compact operator are isolated eigenvalues. Take $f$ to be any continuous function with $f(\lambda)=1$ and zero on all other eigenvalues.